# Docker set up and back end

Tags: windows, macos, docker, flutter

I'm new with Docker and I'm trying to set up my environment. Can I do that on my Mac (for the back-end of an app) while for the front-end I use my Windows pc (Flutter). I just don't want to install Docker on Windows as I have been reading it is a bit of a nightmare. So basically Windows for front-end and Mac for back-end with Dockers.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you can of course but you need to setup firewall rules and know how to access your other computer(s) from your local network. This has not necessarily anything to do with docker itself.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Will try!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of your computers should be in same network and they have an access to each other.